# Show that $\nu(E) = \int_E \phi \,d \mu$ is inner and outer regular.

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, borel-measures

Let $\phi \geq 0$ be a function in $L^1(\mu)$ where $\mu$ is a Radon measure (= a Borel measure on $X$ that is finite on compact sets, inner regular on open sets and outer regular on all compact sets) on the locally compact Hausdorff space $X$. Show that
$$\nu(E) = \int_E \phi \,d \mu$$
is again a Radon measure.

**Attempt**:

Trivially, since $\nu(X) <\infty$, $\nu$ is finite on compact sets. It remains to show that $$\nu(E) = \inf\{\nu(U): U \supseteq E, U \text{ open}\}$$
$$\nu(U) = \sup\{\nu(K): K \subseteq U, K \text{ compact}\}$$

where $E$ is a Borel set of $X$ and $U$ is an open set of $X$. I managed to show that this is true when $\mu(E), \mu(U) < \infty$ by invoking the following:

$$\forall \varepsilon > 0: \exists \delta > 0: \mu(F) < \delta\implies \nu(F) < \varepsilon$$

However, I'm stuck if $\mu(E) = \infty = \nu(U)$. How can I proceed?

Comment: There is a nice related result: If $\psi \in L^1(X, \mu)$, then $\rho(E) := \int_E \psi \, d\mu$ defines a complex measure with variation $|\rho|(E) = \int_E |\psi| \, d\mu$. In particular, such a measure is regular since its variation is regular.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a complete solution (with the help of @Sebastian Spindler):

**(STEP 1)** We show that if $E$ is a Borel set with $\mu(E) < \infty$, then $\nu$ is inner regular at $E$.

Since $\phi \in L^1(\mu)$, we have the following property:

$$\forall \varepsilon > 0: \exists \delta > 0: \mu(F) < \delta \implies \nu(F) = \int_F \phi \,d \mu < \varepsilon$$

Fix $\varepsilon > 0$ and choose the corresponding $\delta > 0$, as above. Then, since $\mu$ is inner regular at $\sigma$-finite Borelsets, we can choose a compact $K \subseteq E$ with $\mu(E\setminus K) < \delta$. Consequently,

$$\nu(E) \leq \nu(K) + \nu(E\setminus K) < \varepsilon + \nu(K) $$

and we conclude that
$$\nu(E) = \sup\{\nu(K): K \subseteq E, K \text{ compact}\}$$

Thus $\nu$ is inner regular at $E$.

**(STEP 2)** We show $\nu$ is inner regular on all Borel subsets.

Let $E$ be a Borel subset of $X$. Note that we have the pointwise limit
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \phi \chi_{E \cap \{\phi > 1/n\}} = \phi\chi_{E \cap \{\phi > 0\}}$$

Hence, invoking the dominated convergence theorem,
$$\nu(E) = \int_E \phi \, d \mu = \int_{E \cap \{\phi > 0\}}\phi \, d \mu = \lim_n \int_{E \cap \{\phi > 1/n\}} \phi \, d \mu = \lim_n \nu(E \cap \{\phi > 1/n\})$$

However, $$\infty > \Vert \phi \Vert_1 \geq \nu(\{\phi > 1/n\}) = \int_{\{\phi>1/n\}} \phi  \, d \mu\geq n^{-1} \mu(\{\phi> 1/n\})$$

Hence, $\mu(E \cap \{\phi> 1/n\}) < \infty$. By (STEP 1), we may select compact sets $K_n \subseteq E \cap \{\phi > 1/n\}$ with $ \nu(E\cap \{\phi > 1/n\})-\nu(K_n)  < 1/n$.

Thus, we see that $\lim_n \nu(K_n)= \nu(E)$ and thus $$\nu(E) = \sup \{ \mu(K): K \subseteq E, K \text{ compact}\}$$

**(STEP 3)** We show $\nu$ is outer regular on all Borel sets.

Let $E$ be a Borel set. Let $\varepsilon > 0$. By (STEP 2), there is a compact subset $K \subseteq E^c$ with $\nu(E^c)- \nu(K) < \varepsilon$. The set $U:= K^c$ is open and contains $E$ and $$\nu(U) - \nu(E) = \nu(X)- \nu(K) - \nu(E) = \nu(E^c) - \nu(K) < \varepsilon$$
Hence, $$\nu(E) = \inf\{\nu(U): U \supseteq E, U \text{ open}\}$$
as desired.

Comment: I think we can use the finiteness of $\nu$ to shorten the proof after step 2 and omit the condition $\phi >0$: For any Borel set $E$ we find a compact $K \subseteq X \setminus E$ such that $\nu(X \setminus E) - \nu(K) < \varepsilon$, so $\nu(X \setminus K) - \nu (E) = \nu(X) - \nu(K) - \nu(E) = \nu(X \setminus E) - \nu(K) < \varepsilon$ and $U := X \setminus K$ is open.

Comment: @Sebastian Spindler. Why can you find such a compact $K$?

Comment: Wait, i mixed something up. But since $\nu$ is finite, we should be able to show that $\nu$ is inner regular everywhere. After that we can find such a $K$.

Comment: We don't know that $\nu$ is inner regular on $X\setminus E$ I think.

Comment: We do know this at least a posteriori since a Radon measure is inner regular on every subset of finite measure, so showing inner regularity instead may help us to drop the condition $\phi > 0$. Is there any point in step 2 where openness of $U$ is actually used? I personally don't see it, but I might be missing something.

Comment: Hmmm, yes it might be the case that $\nu$ is inner regular everywhere. I will think about it some more.

Comment: You are right. Openness is not necessary! Hence we can fix the proof! Thanks, I will make the edit!

Comment: @SebastianSpindler I made the edits. I believe everything works out fine now! Thanks for the help!

Comment: There is one last $U$ in step 2 where step 1 is applied, otherwise everything looks good!

Comment: Thanks again :)